# "Object based Image Segmentation" and some options are absent in SAGA

Tags: geoprocessing, saga, image-segmentation

[image]Although I have the latest version of SAGA, "Object based Image Segmentation" and some options do not appear when I click on "Geoprocessing>Imagery> Segmentation>? " Why are they absent?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. I tried the zip file installation and the exe file, no success.

Finally, I clicked on Geoprocessing > Load Tool Library > I went in modules, toolchains and I selected "obia" xml file. And it worked! Now I have the obia option in imagery/segmentation.

If you're not familiar with SAGA (like myself) this may be the solution to your problem with absent tools.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that If you installed and use SAGA from the downloaded file named **"setup.exe"**(That was what I did), some options don't appear at the menu.[image]

Therefore it seems better to use the software from the **zipped file**. Now all options are seen.

[image]